# Unity 3D GameObjects not visible in HoloLens2, MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-1-introduction and did every step. But when I run it on the HoloLens, I don't see anything.

Build configurations are as in the tutorial, HoloLens2 is in Developer mode and has been paired before. Tools are as in https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools?tabs=unity
I am building the app over WIFI.
When the app starts on HoloLens, mesh appears for a moment and I get a question asking if it is allowed to use on my microphone.
"Build with Unity" or similar does not appear, and no objects either. I see "nothing".
What could be the problem?

I use:
Unity 2021.1.20f
MRTK v1.0.2206. Preview (from Microsoft Download Center)

Comment: Assuming the program launches (you should be able to see it run on the Hololens portal), you probably already did so, but look all around you. And if you see nothing still, then walk away a few meters from where you're standing, and look again. It wouldn't be the first time I've "spawned" inside a mesh, and wondered why I didn't see anything.

Comment: Yes, I can see the project under running apps. And I walk and look around, but I still don't see anything. 
When I use the 3D view in the Device Portal, do I normally see the 3D objects that I should see? Because I don't see anything there either. 
I cannot find the error

Comment: Have you added your scenes to **File->Build Settings->Scenes In Build** before building the project? Can you see the object in **Remote Debugging** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr)? Also, for Unity, the official recommendation is to use the LTS version, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the log file? (`\LocalAppData\YOURAPP\TempState\UnityPlayer.log`) - you will need to terminate the app before you can access it though

Comment: The scene is added. 
No connection is established via remote debugging. 
I get the output when I start the project via Unity: 
"There is no AsyncCoroutineRunner in the scene. Add a GameObject with AsyncCoroutineRunner at the root of the scene." and "This application does not use the recommended Audio Spatializer plugin...".

Okay, then I'll give version 2020.03 a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the wrong Unity version.
I am now using Unity 2020.3.4 and I can see and move the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Unity version to Unity 2021.3.25. Alternatively, you can refer to this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/unhandled-exception-when-debugging-app-to-hololens-2-emulator.1404943/ to add the latest InputSystem package，if you don't want to downgrade your editor version.